# I am using docker for flask and pytesseract container is running but cannot access the page on browser

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, python-tesseract

Using this for DockerFile, on running with 
`docker run -p 5000:5000 flask_app:1.0`
It runs but browser is  showing 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

````
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install tesseract-ocr -y \
    python3 \
    #python-setuptools \
    python3-pip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoremove

ADD . /home/App
WORKDIR /home/App
COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

VOLUME ["/data"]
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are probably listening on interface 127.0.0.1. You need to listen on 0.0.0.0, e.g. `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)`.

Basically the container and your host have different 127.0.0.1, so you need to bind to external IPs. For more details, and diagrams, see https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/

Comment: On going to 0.0.0.0:5000 it shows ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID and on going to localhost:5000 it shows ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Thanks for your help the issue with was that I am using docker toolbox so had to change the host as you suggested and then go http://192.168.99.100:5000/.